# Difference between using objcopy and xxding the file into a c source

Tags: c, embedded-resource, objdump, xxd

Say I want to embed a file called `data` in my C executable.

The result which comes up from google is [this linuxjournal page](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967) which says use `objdump` like this

```
objcopy --input binary \
        --output elf32-i386 \
        --binary-architecture i386 data data.o
```

However this is dependent on the architecture of the computer, for example when compiling the object from the previous command it gives `i386 architecture of input file 'data.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output` and I have to change the arguments.

However with the unix tool [xxd](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xxd1.html), I can simply make a c source code with the data in a unsigned char array and an integer with its length and obtain the same result with device independent compilation commands.

```
data.o: data.c
        gcc -c data.c
data.c: data
        xxd -i data > data.c
```

What is the preferred method and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xxd` is not a standard UNIX tool. It is actually part of VIM and is used for implementing its hex editor function. VIM is an optional tool and is not universally available.

The `GNU objcopy`, on the other hand, is part of GNU binutils and generally is preinstalled on all GNU systems.

In general, when one needs to include a binary file into a program, something simple (as you do with `xxd`) is preferred over the `objcopy`. Mainly, for the simple reason that `objcopy` is heavily under-documented and leaves impression of being an unpolished front-end to the `BFD`, the underlying library of the binutils. Another reason is that along with the `.c` file, you can also create the `.h` file, and make the generated files an integral part of your project.

The article you link already contains a number of examples how to accomplish that. Probably the most popular tool for the purpose is the `hexdump`, preinstalled on literally all systems. For example, from the top of my head:

```
# .c
echo 'char data[] = {' > data.c
hexdump -v  -e '1/1  "0x%02X,"' < data.bin >> data.c
echo >> data.c
echo '};' >> data.c
echo 'size_t data_size = sizeof(data);'
# .h
echo 'extern char data[];' > data.h
echo 'extern size_t data_size;' >> data.h
```